# Compute $\int_C\sin y\,dx+(x\cos y-\sin y)\,dy$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Compute $\int_C\sin y\,dx+(x\cos y-\sin y)\,dy$ where $C$ is $\displaystyle \frac {x^2}{4}+\frac {y^2}{2}=1$ in the first quadrant counter clockwise.

I set $x=2\cos \theta$ and $y=\sqrt{2}\sin\theta$ where $0\leq\theta\leq \frac {\pi}{2}$.

But when I plug $x$ and $y$ back into the integral I am unable to solve it. Please drop some hints.

Thanks.

EDIT:

$\displaystyle\int_{\Gamma}=\iint_D(\frac {\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac {\partial P}{\partial y})\,dA=\int_0^2\int_0^{\sqrt{2}}2\cos y\,dy\,dx=\pi$

$\int_{c_1}+\int_{c_2}=\int_0^20+\int_0^\sqrt{2}-\sin t\,dt$, where

$C_1:$ $x=t,\,dx=dt, y=0,dy=0\,dt, 0\leq t\leq 2$

$C_2: y=t, dy=\,dt, x=0, dx=0\,dt, 0\leq t\leq \sqrt{2}$

So $\displaystyle \int_c=\int_{\Gamma}-\int_{c_1}-\int_{c_2}=\pi-0-\frac {\pi}{4}+1=\frac {3\pi}{4}+1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do this by substitution you get
$$I=\int_0^{\pi/2} -2\sin(\sqrt2\sin\theta)\sin\theta+\sqrt2(2\cos\theta\cos(\sqrt2\sin\theta)-\sin(\sqrt2\sin\theta))\cos\theta\,d\theta$$
(or something like that - I didn't check it carefully) which certainly does not look nice.  So you need a different method.

**Hints**.  Let $C_1$ be the $x$-axis from $0$ to $2$, let $C_2$ be the $y$-axis from $\sqrt2$ to $0$, and let $\Gamma$ be the closed curve consisting of $C$, $C_1$ and $C_2$.  Then

- $\displaystyle \int_\Gamma=\int_C+\int_{C_1}+\int_{C_2}$;
- the integrals along $C_1$ and $C_2$ are easy;
- the integral along $\Gamma$ can be done by Green's Theorem.

Good luck!

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. I've used the method suggested by Felix and got the answer. Now I'm using yours do double check the answer, but how can I find the parameterization along $\int_C$? I am again stuck at $x=2\cos\theta, y=\sqrt{2}\sin\theta$.

Comment: You don't need to do anything at all with $C$, that's the point of this method!  Once you have done the integrals along $\Gamma,C_1$ and $C_2$ you just subtract.

Comment: Thanks again. I've posted my solution using your suggested method in edit. However I got $\frac {\pi}{4}-1$ using Felix's method. Can you check if you got either of my answer?

Comment: You have made a couple of careless errors, I think the answer should be $\cos(\sqrt2)-1$.

Comment: Oh yeah that's all me. I've been studying all day that's probably why. Thanks I will correct them!

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$$
\partiald{F}{x}=\sin\pars{y}\quad\imp\quad F = x\sin\pars{y} + \phi\pars{y}
$$

> $$
> x\cos\pars{y} - \sin\pars{y} =\partiald{F}{y}=x\cos\pars{y} + \phi'\pars{y}
> \quad\imp\quad\phi\pars{y} = \cos\pars{y} + \mbox{constant}
> $$

$$
F = x\sin\pars{y} + \cos\pars{y} + \mbox{constant}\quad\imp\quad
\color{#00f}{\large\int_{C}\dd F = 0}
$$

Comment: That's better than my answer except that $C$ is not a closed curve, so in the final step the integral should be $F(0,\sqrt2)-F(2,0)$.